# NoMethodError at / undefined method `refinery_es_path' for #Module:0xdd2a124

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, multilingual, refinerycms

I am trying to implement the internationalization for the refinary CMS

I am using the GEM

```
    gem 'refinerycms-translate_routes', :git => "git://github.com/the-cocktail/refinerycms-translate-routes.git", :ref => '7fea9fcca5981aaae3bf8cf14b76ba5c679cf23b'
```

with the rails

```
    gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
    gem 'refinerycms', '~> 2.0.9'
    gem 'rails-translate-routes'
```

But when try to put the link for the default language link

```
     <%= link_to Refinery::I18n.locales[:es], refinery.url_for(:locale => :es) %>
```

I am getting the below mention error in root directory of the application. Please suggest me on this regard. I have followed the procedures mentioned in the github directory https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes.
NoMethodError at /

```
    undefined method `refinery_es_path' for #Module:0xdd2a124
```

The above error is coming for only default language, the link creation with the refinery.url_for is working fine for other languages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After RND,itself I got It was getting the error, as because in application controller there was a before_filter action, which was in infinite loop. In the above case same action was calling infinite times. Thanks!!!